# Passing entire data.table to j expression

Tags: r, data.table

I want to use all columns as an object in `j` expression on a grouped data.table (just like tidyverse's `group_modify` function).

So far, I accomplished this by doing:

```
dt[, some_function(data.table(.SD)), some_column, .SDcols = colnames(dt)]
```

But this feels clunky, is there another (simpler) way to do it?

Comment: Proper way seems to be to vectorize your function so it takes groups into account, then you call it on `dt`. Otherwise you can `split.data.table` by grouping columns, `lapply` your fun and `rbindlist`. Your approach is not any worse than those, just replace `f(data.table(.SD))` into `f(as.data.table(.SD))`, or even just `f(.SD)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I thought that there were a built-in function in the package to do this, but looking at it this way that's simple enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there isn't any functions in the package that present this behaviour. The way that makes the code more readable (at least for me) was by creating a wrapper function and use it:

```
temp_fun <- function(f, ...) {
  f(as.data.table(list(...)))
}

dt[, temp_fun(some_function, .SD), some_column]
```